# Why does pyqgis not give error or warning, when opening project with invalid file path

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a stand alone script, that opens a QGIS project file in order to extract details.

I accidentally moved a file and the script broke. Below is the interesting part.

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)
project = QgsProject.instance()
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

project.read('/home/jdoe/textproj.qgz') 
# invalid path, but does not fail or warn in any way

print(project)
# prints: <QgsProject:'/home/jdoe/textproj.qgz'(singleton instance)>
# no indication of any problems with loading file
```

#### Question 1 - Why no error?

I think everyone would expect it to fail (throwing an exception). Is there any good reason for it to behave different than failing?

#### Question 2 - How to properly load a project from a file?

Is there anything in my code that is is using the library differently than intended, which may partly explain why I got no errors?

#### Question 3 - How do I make sure it fails?

Of course I could write my own assertion to test if the path does point to a file. But I guess there could be other ways in which reading/loading a project file could fail. So what is the proper way of catching this right away?

Comment: A similar case is on my side. A short script that fails in line qgs.initQgis() but without any messages with warnings or errors. Just a process closed. (qgis-ltr 3.28.5 in Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

project.read will return `True` if the file reading was successful, and `False` if it was not, [see the documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html#qgis.core.QgsProject.read). So, it is giving an indication of whether it was successful, but in your code, it is currently not being checked for. A simple if-else statement can catch the failure, which you can then adjust to do with what you want, such as quit the code or loop, or give a warning, for a super simple example:

```
if project.read('/home/jdoe/textproj.qgz'):
    #read was successful
    print('Project successfully opened!')
else:
    #read was unsuccessful
    print('Reading project file failed!)
```

As for your first question, I cannot address this as I am not a QGIS developer, but you may have more luck asking in one of the [mailing lists](https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/mailinglists.html).